# returned more than one Version Exception when read other's file

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, read-the-docs

Django Version: 1.8.16
Python Version: 2.7.5

All document is public, you can read all of it even you are not login, but when you login, if you don't have super admin permission, the error message come out

**Exception**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://rtd.chan.net/en/latest/
Django Version: 1.8.16
Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned
Exception Value:    
get() returned more than one Version -- it returned 2!
Exception Location: /www/rtd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 338
Python Executable:  /www/rtd/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['.',
 '',
 '/www/rtd/lib64/python27.zip',
 '/www/rtd/lib64/python2.7',
 '/www/rtd/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/www/rtd/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/www/rtd/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/www/rtd/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/www/rtd/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

**Code**

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Performs the query and returns a single object matching the given
    keyword arguments.
    """
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.query.can_filter():
        clone = clone.order_by()
    num = len(clone)
    if num == 1:
        return clone._result_cache[0]
    if not num:
        raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
            "%s matching query does not exist." %
            self.model._meta.object_name
        )
    raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
        "get() returned more than one %s -- it returned %s!" %
        (self.model._meta.object_name, num)
    )
```

line 338 is `(self.model._meta.object_name, num)`

I try to Google the exception message, the coding solution is to change `get` to `filter`, but it cause another exception and I don't think it's the real solution, how to fix it?

Comment: You have more than one object is returned. Please include your queryset into the description.

Comment: Include the actual code, what you included is still part of the exception.